# Ubuntu 20.04.03 LTS ethernet cable unplugged

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.03 OS on my laptop. Wireless works great but Ethernet seems cable unplugged. When I do "nmcli dev status" Ethernet seems unavailable. I have tried many commands but it doesn't work. Please, can you help me?

Comment: are the led`s on the cable/plugs lit,just to know if it is properly connected to your router.

Comment: _"I have tried many commands"_. What commands did you try and what is the output of the commands? Please provide enough details, so that we can identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you post your /etc/netplan/*.yaml network config file? Also post output of "ip a" command here.